# Random file order

Tags: file, random, sequence

I like to get my files in true random order.

I used "sort by size", but similar files getting after each other.

Is there any solution / software / command which gets my files in a true random order?

Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this as a solution, tested and working: https://sourceforge.net/projects/filerandomizer/